# Which way is better efficient to log user's activites(history) in android?

Tags: android, database, logging

I develop the app which is provide some information to general user.  it is not only showing info but also curating and recommending further detail info depending on users history;what the users clicked, searched and acted on the app. (like a google targeting AD).
For this, I have to accumulate user's activites on apps. (which button was clicked, when did they turn on the app and so on...)

For this, I have two ideas.
1. let the app to leave their log text file in local device then append lines in it whenever user act, and upload it when they turn off the app on server DB.[like a batch]
-OR-
2. let the app, update db everytime when user acts something on app by http-post.[like a realtime]

Which way is common tactics(or popular ways) on real field? or can you suggest another way?
thanks for reading.

Comment: Maybe you should try to use Google analytics in your app? Do you want to perform your own analisys of user behaviour?

Comment: I already used that one. but it doesn't provide what I want, and cant make custom log as i know. (sorry, i am not sure.).  
Important thing is that I need my data in my own DB sever.